# Not able to close jquery UI modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is the function to open dialog. and I open html form in the dialog but i tried every thing but not able to close modal popup.

```
function PopupDialog(id,title,height,width,draggable) {

        $("#"+id).dialog({
            modal: true,
            title: title,
            height: height,
            width: width,
            draggable: draggable,
            stack: false,

        });
    }
```

I am opening below mentioned div in the modal popup.

```
<div id="specialtyDetail">

<div class="fadeoutPatch0"></div>
<div class="fadeoutBackground" id="fbspecialtyDetail"></div>

<div id="tblspecialtyDetail" class="col-md-12">

                <form method="get" id="frmSpecialtyDetail">
                    <!--start - CONTENTS-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <label class="control-label">Short Name <span class="required">*</span></label>
                            <input class="form-control size100" name="ShortName" id="txtShortName" type="text" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-4 pad-a-labelsize">
                            <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
                                <input type="checkbox" checked="" id="chkActive">
                                <label for="Active">Active</label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            <label class="control-label">Description</label>
                            <input class="form-control" id="txtDescription" type="text" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6 pad-a-labelsize-btn">
                            <div class="btn-block">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="reset" onclick="specialtyDetail.SpecialtySave_OnClick();">Save</button>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="reset" onclick="specialtyDetail.SpecialtyUnload();">Cancel</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>

</div>
```

I want to close dialog on save button click.

Comment: have you tried this `$( "#your-id" ).dialog( "close" );` ?

Comment: Check the link :- [link](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#method-close)

Comment: yes I have tried but it will not work for me

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle?

Comment: works.. sorry guys I am passing wrong id...Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work. Call this function with id

```
function closeDialog(id){
    $("#"+id).dialog('close')
}
```